# easy functions on data in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

My example df:

```
a = c(2,2,4) 
b = c(3,4,5) 
c = c(3,5,7) 
d = c(3,5,8)
df = data.frame(a, b, c, d)
```

I want to normalize col b-d by dividing it through column a.
Like this (for the specific example of col b)

```
df$b <- df$b / df$a
```

But I have so many columns in reality. So I want to use some loop. 
Something like this:

```
for (x in df[c(2:4)]){
  df$x <- df$x / df$a
}
```

Do I need an apply function here? Or am I missing some comma or bracket?

Comment: `df[, 2:4] / df[, 1]`?

Comment: `df[, c("b", "c", "d")] <- as.matrix(df[, c("b", "c", "d")])/df$a`

Comment: `df[, names(df) != "a"] <- df[, names(df) != "a"] / df[, "a"]`

Comment: You should study `help("$")`. This is a FAQ. If you want to fix your loop, use `[]` instead of `$`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divide all columns by the value from the 2nd column - apply for all rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299206/divide-all-columns-by-the-value-from-the-2nd-column-apply-for-all-rows)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), specify the columns in `.SDcols`, divide the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) by the 'a' column and assign (`:=`) to columns of interest

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (2:4) := .SD/a,.SDcols = 2:4]
df
#   a    b    c   d
#1: 2 1.50 1.50 1.5
#2: 2 2.00 2.50 2.5
#3: 4 1.25 1.75 2.0
```